# How to position an image precisely on a background image in Flutter using image coordinates?

Tags: flutter, stack, position, flutter-image, networkimageview

I'm attempting to overlay an image on top of another image using dynamic image coordinates and adding dynamic image scale values. I've employed a Stack as the parent widget, with the two image widgets as children. However, I'm facing challenges aligning their positions and scales accurately.

I am attaching screenshot of background image. I need to place another image on white space.

Background Image:-

[image]

Second Image :-

[image]

Image Coordinates:-

```
{
 'img_width: 540, '
      'img_height: 960, '
      'image_coordinates: {'
      'width_in_px: 280, '
      'height_in_px: 398, '
      'top_in_px: 405, '
      'left_in_px: 173, '
      'width: 51.85, '
      'height: 41.46, '
      'top: 62.92, '
      'left: 57.97, '
      'type: box}
}
```

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class EditActivity extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  _EditActivity createState() => new _EditActivity();
}

class _EditActivity extends State<EditActivity> {

  String image = 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/ACg8ocKeSe_PhCD8mS7RySGmfDcwAcnHbiEXEk5fv4G2fTqbce4=s576-c-no';
  String bgImage = 'https://files.verbs.world/2023/11/13/19/Zf13UiLP8.PNG';

  String coordinates = ''
      'img_width: 540, '
      'img_height: 960, '
      'image_coordinates: {'
      'width_in_px: 280, '
      'height_in_px: 398, '
      'top_in_px: 405, '
      'left_in_px: 173, '
      'width: 51.85, '
      'height: 41.46, '
      'top: 62.92, '
      'left: 57.97, '
      'type: box}';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            
            Container(
              width: 540,
              height: 960,
              child: Image.network(bgImage,fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,),
            ),
            Positioned(left: 173,top: 408 ,child: Container(
              color: Colors.amber,
              width: 280,
              height: 398,
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Image.network(image,fit: BoxFit.cover,width: 280,
                height: 398,
              ),
            ),)

          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I'm attempting to overlay an image on top of another image using dynamic image coordinates and adding dynamic image scale values. I've employed a Stack as the parent widget, with the two image widgets as children. However, I'm facing challenges aligning their positions and scales accurately.

Comment: original coordinates are a bit wrong so a padding of 5 pixels needs to be added: `body: FittedBox( child: SizedBox.fromSize( size: const Size(540, 960), child: Stack( children: [ Image.file(File('lib/img1.png'), fit: BoxFit.none), Positioned.fromRect(rect: const Rect.fromLTWH(173, 405, 280, 398).deflate(5), child: Image.file(File('lib/img2.png'), fit: BoxFit.cover), ), ], ), ), ),`

Comment: Thank you pskink , It's working for all images. Thanks for the response.

Comment: your welcome, btw if you want to show the whole image in the frame you can remove `fit: BoxFit.cover`

Comment: Okay got it , you saved my time. once again thank you.

Comment: again, your welcome

Answer (score 0):

Change Positioned for center and use padding for move to site you need, In the Stack, put the image first and then the background so that it fits you better.

```
class EditActivity extends StatefulWidget {
  const EditActivity({super.key});

  @override
  _EditActivity createState() => _EditActivity();
}

class _EditActivity extends State<EditActivity> {
  String image =
      'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/ACg8ocKeSe_PhCD8mS7RySGmfDcwAcnHbiEXEk5fv4G2fTqbce4=s576-c-no';
  String bgImage = 'https://files.verbs.world/2023/11/13/19/Zf13UiLP8.PNG';

  String coordinates = ''
      'img_width: 540, '
      'img_height: 960, '
      'image_coordinates: {'
      'width_in_px: 280, '
      'height_in_px: 398, '
      'top_in_px: 405, '
      'left_in_px: 173, '
      'width: 51.85, '
      'height: 41.46, '
      'top: 62.92, '
      'left: 57.97, '
      'type: box}';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      body: SizedBox(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                left: 92,
                top: 240,
              ),
              child: Center(
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.amber,
                  width: 280,
                  height: 398,
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Image.network(
                    image,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    width: 280,
                    height: 398,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Center(
              child: SizedBox(
                width: 540,
                height: 960,
                child: Image.network(
                  bgImage,
                  fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Franklin , Thanks for the quick response. But you added extra padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                left: 92,
                top: 240,
              ),
Padding for the left and top will be specified for this image. However, if the background image is altered, these padding values may not be effective. The goal is to ensure that the padding functions correctly for all images.

Comment: Yes , I tried. It fixed for above image only.

Comment: It's true, my approach was wrong, the solution in pskink's comment is great.

Comment: Yes ... It's working for all images. Its a great approach.